# css animation applied to root element behaving strangely

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-animations

i'm trying to apply a css animation to the root element of a page and it's behaving strangely.  you can see it here:  [http://dinakelberman.com/bucket/circle-test.html](https://dinakelberman.com/bucket/circle-test.html)

```css
html {
display:block;
transition-duration:1.5s;
background:#E3DCB1;
background-image:url(http://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/leapfrog/images/b/be/Yellow_Circle.png/revision/latest?cb=20180115233859);
background-size:100%;
animation:rotate 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 0% {transform:rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);}
 100% {transform:rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg);}
}
```

- in chrome & opera the animation progresses only when the mouse moves
- in safari it animates on its own as expected
- in firefox it doesn't animate at all

i don't need a solution as to how to make this animation visible by using other elements, i know this is a weird and wrong way to do things.

i'm doing some experimental work where i'm trying to deal exclusively with the root element.  i don't really dislike the behaviors but ideally i'd like the results to be the same across browsers so i'm curious about how they're handling this differently.

Comment: animating the html isn't a good idea. It's not meant to get animated or even styled which somehow explain the behavior

Comment: by the way add `height:100%` because actually your are facing backgroud propagation and you see the canvas not the html